# Mysql in clause with multidimensional array

Tags: mysql

I want to query a table say tab A, having 6 columns say 1-6.

I'm selecting columns 2 and 5 where column 1 is in an array, the array is a select statement for another table tab B also having say 6 columns.

EG.

```
select col2, col5 from tab A where col1 in (select col4 from tab B)
```

Now i want col 6 from tab B for each case that tabA.col1 is found in tabB.col4 array

So i'm looking for a final output say....

```
tabA.col2    tabA.col5    tabB.col6
xxxx         xxxx         xxxx
xxxx         xxxx         xxxx
xxxx         xxxx         xxxx
xxxx         xxxx         xxxx
```

So i'm wondering is it possible to pass a multidimensional array and then specify the column of interest. After which get data in other field of array

This kinda feels incredible, Lol. So I hope this is possible. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint : `JOIN`. Research and try something.

Comment: @BhavikPatel ok that helps, but i was actually doing a distinct(tabB.col4), but now when i join on tabA.col1 = tabB.col4 i get more results than i had when i did distinct(). I cant really explain why.

Comment: @BhavikPatel In other words... what is the possible reason why the 2 queries (select distinct(col1) from tabA) and (select distinct(col1), col2 from tab A) will produce different results

Comment: can you please update the new query which you have tried?